# Wordpress - Remove dynamically generated style sheet?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I made a wordpress site and it has an error in which a "dynamically generated style sheet" creates this style:

## content {width: 0px;}

This causes all of my content to squish to the left. http://wp.townsendsites.com
Is there a way to get rid of this, or override it in either the php or css?

Comment: Override it with `#content > * {max-width: 100%;}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite a markup that cannot be overwritten, use: `width: 80% !important;`
it's not the best practice, but it works. 80% is an example.

Answer (score 0):

A neater way to solve the problem isn't to try and override the styles; it's to work out why those styles are there in the first place.

I've had a *very* quick poke around the theme and I can see that the dynamic stylesheet is generating its styles based on theme settings; the theme should have an extra options screen in the admin area where you can enter your own width for content.

Failing that you can comment out line 619 from 'functions.php' which currently reads "add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bitLumen_enqueue_dynamic', 10 );"
That's the line that loads up the dynamic stylesheet

I'd recommend you try and find the settings in the admin area first; no sense trying to brute force your styles with !important rules